# The import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams cannot be resolved

Tags: java

The Java code -

```
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
```

I cannot see this class in httpcore5-5.0.1.jar
I am upgrading httpcore-4.1.jar to httpcore5-5.0.1.jar.

Comment: It looks like the use of `HttpParams` changed in v4.3: `Deprecation of preference and configuration API based on HttpParams interface in favor of constructor injection and plain configuration objects.` Unfortunately, I've never used HttpParams, but that seems why it's not present in the newer version.

Comment: The previous information was [found here](https://hc.apache.org/news.html), in the `12 September 2013` release notes.

Comment: @PaulT. for future reference the "apache" tag is specifically for the Apache HTTP Server, not for everything under the Apache project.